# How do you make a program that automates web browsing but not in a browser?

Tags: browser-automation

I wrote a program in python that used selenium to automate a web browser (firefox). It worked well but I have seen programs that automate web browsing but instead it seems to be in some kind of window or frame (iframe?) and not in a browser. How do you do this? Is it faster because the window only focuses on that one specific website?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I don't know...I downloaded a program and ran it and it opened up a window and automated internet browsing on one specific website for me.

Here is the download: 
http://bankhead11.webs.com/downloads.htm
It is the first one.
(its an old program. people have reported that it stopped working years ago because the person stopped updating it. but a lot of people used it to "automatically bid" on a website for money. I don't want to explain that...but currently I want to make two programs. One will automatically bid in real time for me and the other will use a google api and submit data to a website)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Are you talking about a standard application (like a Windows app, for example) that has a web browser-type control inside it?  Like, for example, Visual Studio displays web content in the Welcome page using a WebBrowser control, rather than opening an instance of Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, or some other browser.  Is that what you're talking about?  Although just knowing that wouldn't help unless you also told us what you've tried, what language you're focusing on, or what specific questions you have.  Can you edit and clarify?

Comment: Or at least give us an example of a program that does what you're talking about, and maybe a screenshot.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "web browsing"? Do you want to scrape webpages? Do some interactive work (i.e. submit form data)?

Comment: Well, in .NET you'd create either a Windows Forms application or a WPF application and use a WebBrowser control.  Both paradigms offer a WebBrowser control that can be used like this.  It's often overkill and it's usually better to just use the customer's browser to go to a given web page, but the capability is there.  I'm not sure about other languages/platforms.  Either way, this is far to broad to be answerable.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. So you're saying that's what *they* used? .NET?

Comment: No, I'm saying that it ***can*** be done easily in .NET.  (And that comes to mind because I'm primarily a .NET developer.)  I'm sure it ***can*** be done with Java, C, C++, or whatever.  The approach is probably different.

Answer (score 0):

Performing automation in browser is the best way to test the application, instead of some app testing on some different window/Frame. You can test the functionality but that testing will be incomplete until you test on Actual browser.

If you are looking for fastest way of browser automation, selenium do provide you with an Option of "HTMLUNIT" driver (No GUI), it's much more faster than any browser automation.

check the following link for more details

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#selenium-webdriver-s-drivers

Hope this helps you ..All the best:)